# Elasticsearch jdbc river import slow

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I'm trying to import a sqlserver database to ES with jdbc river but the import process is very slow. In the logs I see that the process is doing the import 1 by 1:

```
new bulk [58] of [1 items], 1 outstanding bulk requests
bulk [58] success [1 items] [116ms]
new bulk [59] of [1 items], 1 outstanding bulk requests
bulk [59] success [1 items]
```

How can I speed up the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my sql sentence. There was a left join that was doing that the performance of the query goes really down, so the import was slow too.

Comment: Hi David, can you share the JSON you used to setup the river?? I spending days on it without any success. I can't make it index my sql tables.